# jQuery validation submit button is not working

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I would like to ask for help fixing this code for mobile validation.
I've fixed the issue regarding my validation but my problem right now is that it won't submit my form. When I tried to remove type="button" on the submit div, It will send the form regardless if there's an error message. Maybe there's any other way without removing the type="button".

Here's my jquery code.

```
        <script>
        function showError(sel, msg) {
            var selector = sel;
            $(selector).text(msg).show();
        }

    function hideError(sel, msg) {
        var selector = sel;
        $(selector).text("").hide();
    }


    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#lbform button').click(function() {
            var errormsg = 0;
            var gender = $("select[name=gender2]").val();
            var sel = ".error-msg-gender";
            if (gender) {
                hideError(sel, msg);
                errormsg = 0;
            } else {
                var msg = "This field is required";
                showError(sel, msg);
                errormsg = 1;
            }

            var val = $("input[name=firstname]").val();
            var sel = ".error-msg-fname";
            if (val && val.length > 1) {
                var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/;
                if (pattern.test(val)) {
                    hideError(sel, msg);
                    errormsg = 0;
                } else {
                    var msg = "Should only contains letters and spaces.";
                    showError(sel, msg);
                    errormsg = 1;
                }
            } else {
                var msg = "Should have at least 2 characters.";
                showError(sel, msg);
                errormsg = 1;
            }

            var year = $(".year").val();
            var month = $(".month").val();
            var day = $(".day").val();
            var sel = ".error-msg-dob";
            if (year && month && day) {
                hideError(sel, msg);
                errormsg = 0;
            } else {
                var msg = "All fields must not be empty.";
                showError(sel, msg);
                errormsg = 1;
            }

            var email = $("input[name=email]").val();
            var sel = ".error-msg-email";
            if (email) {
                var pattern = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

                if (pattern.test(email)) {
                    hideError(sel, msg);
                    errormsg = 0;
                } else {
                    var msg = "Not a valid email address.";
                    showError(sel, msg);
                    errormsg = 1;
                }
            } else {
                var msg = "Email field must not be empty.";
                showError(sel, msg);
                errormsg = 1;
            }



            var password = $("input[name=password]").val();
            var sel = ".error-msg-pass";
            if (password) {
                if (password.length > 3) {
                    hideError(sel, msg);
                    errormsg = 0;
                } else {
                    var msg = "Should have at least 4 characters.";
                    showError(sel, msg);
                    errormsg = 1;
                }
            } else {
                var msg = "Password field must not be empty.";
                showError(sel, msg);
                errormsg = 1;
            }

            if(errormsg == 0) { $("#lbform").trigger("submit"); }
            else {}

        });
    }); 
    </script>
```

Here's my html:

```
    <form id="lbform" class="formlayout" action="http://www.ediwow.com/signup.cfm" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="magic">
            <input type="hidden" value="1" name="sexuality">
        </div>

        <div class="row cf">
            <select name="gender2" id="dating-gender2" class="required gender gender2">
                <option value="1" selected="selected">Man looking for a woman</option>
                <option value="2">Woman looking for a man</option>
            </select>
            <div class="error-msg-gender"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row cf">
            <input type="text" class="text blur" placeholder="First name:" name="firstname">
            <div class="error-msg-fname"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row cf">
            <select class="day" name="dobday">
                <option value="">Day</option>
                <option value="1">01</option>
                <option value="2">02</option>
                <option value="3">03</option>

                <option value="4">04</option>
                <option value="5">05</option>
                <option value="6">06</option>
                <option value="7">07</option>
                <option value="8">08</option>
                <option value="9">09</option>

                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="13">13</option>
                <option value="14">14</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>

                <option value="16">16</option>
                <option value="17">17</option>
                <option value="18">18</option>
                <option value="19">19</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="21">21</option>

                <option value="22">22</option>
                <option value="23">23</option>
                <option value="24">24</option>
                <option value="25">25</option>
                <option value="26">26</option>
                <option value="27">27</option>

                <option value="28">28</option>
                <option value="29">29</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
                <option value="31">31</option>
            </select>

            <select class="month" name="dobmonth">
                <option value="">Month</option>
                <option value="1">January</option>
                <option value="2">February</option>
                <option value="3">March</option>
                <option value="4">April</option>
                <option value="5">May</option>
                <option value="6">June</option>
                <option value="7">July</option>
                <option value="8">August</option>
                <option value="9">September</option>
                <option value="10">October</option>
                <option value="11">November</option>
                <option value="12">December</option>
            </select>

            <select class="year" name="dobyear">
                <option value="">Year</option>
                <?php for($x=date("Y") - 18; $x >= 1918; $x--): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $x; ?>">
                        <?php echo $x; ?>
                    </option>
                    <?php endfor; ?>
            </select>
            <div class="error-msg-dob"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- The <p> tags below can be swapped from an image. -->
        <div class="continue-btn">
            <a onclick="showHide('example');return false;" class="showLink" id="example-show" href="#">
                    Continue
                </a>
        </div>

        <!-- Anything that sits in the div class=more will be hidden until the Continue link is clicked -->
        <div class="more" id="example">
            <div class="row cf">
                <input type="text" class="text blur" placeholder="Email:" name="email" id="email">
                <div class="error-msg-email"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="row cf">
                <input type="password" value="" name="password" placeholder="Password:" id="password">
                <div class="error-msg-pass"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="row cf">
                <button class="header" type="button">JOIN FREE</button>
            </div>

            <div class="row cf">
                <span class="note">By clicking 'Join Free' you are agreeing to our <br><a title="Terms of use" href="http://www.ediwow.com/terms" class="orange-color" target="blank">Terms of Use</a></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: I suggest to use return fun() in the form tag for validation

Comment: @Anandhunadesh didn't get what you mean. what's with return fun()?

Comment: onsubmit = return validate()

Comment: change the button to submit. then add the above in form tag. Return true from validate() only if all the validation conditions are satisfied else return false,so that the form won't submit

Comment: @Anandhunadesh show me your structure pls

Comment: check my answer

Comment: Your code has nothing to do with the jQuery Validate plugin.  Please be more mindful when tagging.  Edited.

Answer (score 0):

change ur form like this

```
 <form id="lbform" class="formlayout" action="http://www.ediwow.com/signup.cfm" method="post" onsubmit= "return validate()">

    // form elements

     <div class="row cf">
           <input type="submit" class="header" value="JOIN FREE">
     </div>
</form>
```

Then create validate function like this

```
<script>
function validate()
{
 var status=true;
 var gender = $("select[name=gender2]").val();
if( /*check ur validation condition here for ex:*/ gender=""  )
   {
     status=false;//add this line whenever the validation return false
     //Display message if needed
   }

//Rest of the validation like the above
//status remain true only if all the validation conditions satisfied.else it becomes false

return status;//return the current value in status after all val conditions are considered.
}
</script>
```

Comment: Status should really be a boolean true or false not "true" or "false" which are strings.

Comment: @Steve Yup thanx. made the changes. But it worked fine for me BTW